# No such file or directory for relative path

Tags: python, bottle, fastcgi

I have a bottle application in one python file - backend.py. The file contains these definitions:

```
variable = {
    'field': [f for f in csv.DictReader(open('../data/fields.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=';')]
}

def run_fcgi():
    from bottle import FlupFCGIServer
    run(port=8080, server=FlupFCGIServer)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8087, server='waitress')
```

When I run this app like:

```
python backend.py
```

application is started successfully.

When I run this application as fcgi application (fcgi.py) by supervisor:

```
#!my_path_to_python

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import backend
    backend.run_fcgi()
```

I have an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path_to_my_project/fcgi.py", line 9, in <module>
    import backend
  File "path_to_my_project/backend.py", line 49, in <module>
    'msk': [i for i in csv.DictReader(open('../data/fields.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=';')],
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../data/fields.csv'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: There is an error in your code miss ")" in first line. Then try to write the full path with `r` before (e.g. r"fullpath\filename.csv").

Comment: Thanks. I've copied the code wrong and forget ')'. With absolute path it works. But why does not work the relative path?

Answer (score 4):

I think It's better not to rely on working directory. and use path relative to file that is uses this path. I mean you can calculate path on the fly:

```
import os
csv_path = '../data/fields.csv'
csv_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), csv_path)
```

In this case one be able to run your script on different environment. an full path will be used to be sure that You don't depends on working directory.