# Why is my code giving me a "mystica.json not found" error?

Tags: python

I'm trying to load some variables from a json file but the file can't be found.

I've tried deleting the file and making it again, renaming it, and moving the file around, but none have worked.

```
def loadVar():
    with open('mystica.json') as read_file:
        variables = json.load(read_file)
        return variables
```

I expect it to grab the values from `mystica.json`, but it gives me the error

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'mystica.json'

Comment: Try using a full path to the file?

Comment: Maybe add a `print(os.getcwd())` to get an idea about the working directory. Don't forget to `import os` for this.

Comment: Make sure either: 1. `mystica.json` is in the same path as where you're running the script, or 2. you pass the file's full path, as suggested by @kindall

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No such file or directory for relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18934775/no-such-file-or-directory-for-relative-path)